# Spring - Can I get the id of a object inside a @Query?

Tags: spring

I have a query in a JpaRepository like this :

```
@Query("SELECT p "
        + "FROM Physicians p "
        + "JOIN Physicianspecialities ps ON (ps.idphysician = p.id AND ps.idspeciality = ?1 AND ps.validfrom <= ?2 AND (ps.validto >= ?2 OR ps.validto IS NULL)) "
        + "JOIN Personnel pe ON (pe.id = p.idPersonnel and pe.validfrom <= ?2 AND (pe.validto >= ?2 OR pe.validto IS NULL)) "
        + "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
List<Physicians> getAllByDateAndSpeciality(Integer idSpeciality, Date date);
```

I know the query is wrong because ps.idspeciality represents the Specialities class and ?1 is an integer.
Is there any syntax that allows writing something like this: "ps.idspeciality.id = ?1" ?

I know that the are other sollutions like

- I can create a Specialities object and use it for comparison.
- I can make an extra JOIN
- or I can make idspeciality integer

But I was wondering if I can't solve this in a more simple way using the @Query language.
Truth is I don't know where could I find the documentation for the language contained in the @Query annotation.

Comment: It is a bit hard to follow without seeing your schema or what you are trying to achieve. You can find the documentation for JPQL here (latest): https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/#jpa_langref

Comment: isnt `ps.idspeciality.id` valid already? As long as FK is kept on `ps` side it will be fine. If it is on the other side, then join is required (or query can be rewriten somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can actually access the id property in the @Query using the syntax "ps.idspeciality.id" I was getting a generic error and I wrongly assumed this was the cause.